# About "AND" Which one is correct? And Why?

Tags: sentence-construction, ambiguity, compound-subjects

How can I understand the sentence below?

> My best friend and my father’s father both come from Wales.

Which one of these is correct? And Why?

> A. My best friend and my father's father (Grandfather) both come from Wales. (My best friend comes from Wales; and my grandfather comes from Wales)
>
> B. My best friend's father and my father's father both come from Wales.

Comment: Aren't your A and B the same?

Comment: @urnonav There is a trivial difference which doesn't affect the use of AND. So yes, there are the same. I think I don't actually understand the question: why do you think either might be incorrect?

Comment: There are possible answers to this: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86993/apostrophe-in-multiple-plural-posession), or [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/preferred-way-to-apostrophise-in-case-of-dual-or-multiple-ownership-by-distinct).

Comment: For A, my friend and my grandpa. For B, My friend's father and my grandpa, actually. And the question is "My best friend and my father’s father both come from Wales. How can i understand the below question?" Actually my question is about "AND" connector. So please help me understand AND in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the sentence to mean version A.

For the meaning to be B you would have to add a possessive:

> My best friend's and my father’s father both come from Wales.

But when spoken you can't tell whether it is **friend's** or **friends** and it relies on the "both" clue to distinguish. So I think your B is clearer

> My best friend's father and my father's father both come from Wales.

Comment: Nah. I don't think it's credible to postulate plural ***friends*** (implying *multiple* "best friends" who come from Wales, as does the speaker's grandfather). That would be like saying *My **children and my wife** BOTH speak English* - which I'd say is inherently invalid, because the construction ***both X and Y*** implies that both ***X*** and ***Y*** are "singular" entities.

Comment: ...stretching a point, we could suppose the speaker has two or more best friends, *who are **brothers***. In which case the highlighted words in ***My best friends and my father**'s father* could feasibly (though awkwardly) be intended to be parsed as ***both*** being modified by the Saxon genitive (so we're talking about their father and my grandfather). But that's *really* stretching a point!

Comment: @FumbleFingers but still, the last version is more clear and immediately obvious. My brain is analysing a sentence before 'both' is reached later on.

Comment: Yeah - your final version is definitely a better choice than anything relying on the audience / reader to make sense of inherently ambiguous constructions. Mind you, the "awkward squad" might still propose parsing ***My best friend's father AND my father*** as a single syntactic unit where the Saxon Genitive modifies ***both*** components - so in a roundabout way, we're talking about ***my best friend's grandfather*** AND ***my grandfather***. God, sometimes I hate English!

Answer (score 1):

> My best friend and my father’s father both come from Wales.

The answer is (A) - the two people that come from Wales are:

1. Your best friend
2. Your grandfather.

The reason you may be wondering about option B (that it refers to your friend's father) is perhaps because you have seen a sentence like this:

> Both my *friend's* and my father are from Wales.

The difference is the possessive form of "my friend". This would indicate that it is your friend's father, and your father who are both from Wales.